# Can anyone help me with this React Native issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone help me with this React Native issue?

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: Can you include the **full stacktrace** along with the code that threw the error? Show us your `App` component at the very least, since the error seems to be occurring there.

Comment: It works thank you very much !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {View,TextInput,Button} from 'react-native';
```

Add the export default Search to your Search component like this,

replace your Search.js with this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View,TextInput,Button} from 'react-native';

 class Search extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop:50}}>
        <TextInput placeholder='Titre du film'/>
        <Button title='Rechercher' onPress={() => {}}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
 export default Search;
```

[image]

Hope this helps!